# Matlab fmincon settings not enough change in variables

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using fmincon for the first time. I have this BlackBox which I can't discribe in details but it is a Numerical Analysis which have an error of ~`1e-2` down to ~`1e-4`. Even if I give exact same input variables.

I've been monitoring the fmincon variables and the changes it makes from the start-point values are way to small to make difference in the model and it's probably just trying to find the gradient of numerical analysis error.

```
mc = 0;         % My Default value
pmc = 0;        % My Default value
t = 0.1200;     % My Default value

% Setup for fmincon
ObjFcn = @run_transonic_wing_fluent_template;
X0   = [mc,    pmc,    t]; nvars = length(X0);           % Variables - Default values!
A = [];
B = [];
Aeq = []; 
Beq = [];
LB  = [0,     0,      0.07];        % Lower Boundaries
UB  = [0.095,     0.9,    0.20];        % Upper Boundaries
NONLCON = [];
OPTIONS = optimset('MaxIter',600, 'MaxFunEval',600, 'TolX',1e-4);


[X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN] = fmincon(ObjFcn, X0, A, B, Aeq, Beq, LB,UB, NONLCON, OPTIONS);
```

START POINT X(0):

```
X(0) = [0, 0, 0.12] -> BlackBox(X(0)) = 1.704732e-02
```

FMINCON tries following points.

```
X'(1) = [0, 0, 0.12]        -> BlackBox(X'(1)) = 1.704732e-02 
X'(2) = [1.49e-08, 0, 0.12] -> BlackBox(X'(2)) = 1.704732e-02 
X'(3) = [0, 1.49e-08, 0.12] -> BlackBox(X'(3)) = 1.704732e-02 
X'(4) = [0, 0, 0.12]]       -> BlackBox(X'(4)) = 1.704732e-02
```

After those four points it says: Local minimum found that satisfies the constraints and gives me `X = [0, 0, 0.12]`
But I know it didn't even try changing the value of t? And the variables m and p won't do anything to my geometry unless they both have values above 0. So all these four simulations give exactly the same geometry.

These value changes of  `1.49e-08` have no real effect on the solution. Is it possible to make the change more aggressive respective to the Boundaries I've set?

Comment: Are `X(0)` and `X(1) etc initialization value of the optimization? You would hope that the solution of the optimization is independent (or not very sensitive) to the initial condition. Why would you expect different results?

Comment: X(0) is the start-point which I randomly gave. X'(1) is the values of the first iteration, X'(2) is the values of second iteration e.t.c. FMINCON doesn't seem to try changing any of the variables significantly and gives me a local minimum at the starting point. The function didn't even explore towards the upper and lower boundaries of all variables.

Comment: Try changing the `DiffMinChange` in the optimset to say `0.1`. Also I assume that you have tried to you function with different values and know that given certain parameters, the output value can become smaller (note you are searching for the min not max of the function, simple negation can reverse that).

Comment: @mpaskov - Yes, I'm currently trying that with normalized variables. I have set the  I've set `LB = [0,0,0]`  -  `UB = [1,1,1]` and `'DiffMinChange',0.05` (5%) in the Optimizing file....

And within the function I have `LB  = [0,0,0.07]` , `UB  = [0.095,0.9,0.20]` and `X = LB+X.*(UB-LB)`. I'm still waiting for the first results but the first iteration variables look promising!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `MaxFunEval` has a suspiciously low value (10). Please increase it to 1000 and see how it goes. Does it change anything?

Comment: More of a comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: @mpaskov Given the information this was the best answer I could think of. In fact I tested it with a tiny example: it failed to converge because maximum function evaluations limit was reached. Increasing this parameter allowed the algorithm to find a solution. So yes, I think it is a valid candidate answer.

Comment: Fair enough. But this will highly depend on what `@MyBlackBox` is. To answer the question properly we truly need more information, that is why I believe we should comment as to improve the quality of the question, before attempting to answer it.

Comment: I agree to a point; I just took `@MyBlackBox` to be literally a black box :-), so I suggested the most obvious improvement. Anyway, still no news from the OP...

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question and tried using higher MaxFunEval = 600. (Same as the default would give).

Comment: So now fmincon claims that it has found a solution. How about trying with different initial values? Can you run a couple of experiments and let us know?

Comment: I believe that DiffMinChange is the one I've been looking for. I've changed it and it's going for more significant changes. Now it made 18 iterations and gave me `X(18) = [0.0189 0.27900 0.133617]`. It is definatly improving. Thanks all for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `FunctionTolerance` and `StepTolerance` ?

Comment: No, I have not. Will take a look at how they work and give them a try! Thanks.

Comment: When I type `optimset('fmincon')` there is no such option. There is one `TolFun`

Comment: According to the documentation, those options are available for `fmincon`. I've tried it in R2016b. This is the link for the R2017a online documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html